# Visual C# cant find my Iconic Zip .dll file

Tags: c#, .net, dll, zip

I am trying to use IconicZip to perform some unzipping tasks in my Visual C# 4.0 application. But when i try to test my application, i receive the error: `Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

My library for IconicZip is located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client` with all the other default libraries.

I've added the reference to it using the add reference wizard and it shows no errors in the code:

```
using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(uiFindRar.FileName))
{  
    foreach (ZipEntry zip in zip1)
    {
        zip.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

The only error i experience is during runtime.

Comment: Don't copy assemblies to that folder; it won't do any good.  Instead, just use NuGet.

Comment: Try setting `Copy Local` on the `Ionic.Zip` to `True`

Comment: "or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." It's also worth checking if all the needed dependencies are installed, use Dependency Walker, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify your assembly reference has Copy Local = true. Often times the assembly reference will default to False because Visual Studio expects the DLL to be in the Global Assembly Cache:

[image]

Comment: if you are using `PackageReference` you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105073/426315) link

Comment: Excellent point, @itsho, but that link is about excluding assemblies, and this question is about including them. Also this question predates PackageReference by about 3 years.. That being said, is there a way to improve the answer that addresses PackageReference for including assemblies where it would otherwise not?

Comment: @wizulus you are correct, I think that `PackageReference` are all CopyLocal=True by default. the reason I added the comment is because I had an issue and found out that one of the projects with package.config had CopyLocal=True and the other project had `PackageReference` with the ignore flag. so I had to "align" the project files.